# Scanning with android camera

Tags: android, android-camera, scanning

How android camera can be used as scanner to scan the device, like in iOS we have AVCaptureDevice & AVCaptureSession classes.

I have tried following -
1. Open CV - result are not good
2. Suggestion which are already available on Google & stack overflow, but none seems to provide good answer.

Is there some free SDK available which can be used?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV is very easy as it is free of charge. You can find an example of a place you hang out in the thousands can benefit from your own library.

but you can also use very complicated BoofCV